# Method arguments set object attributes

Tags: python, meta-programming

The code creates a meta class and its implementation to set the values passed in as arguments to methods on a class automatically on the object avoiding a lot of `self.a=a` code at the start of methods.

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> def setMethodAttrs(func):
...    @wraps(func)
...    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...        formalArgs=inspect.getargspec(func)[0]
...        if len(args)>1:
...           for x in range(1, len(args)):
...              setattr(args[0], formalArgs[x], args[x])
...        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
...           setattr(vars()['args'][0], k, v)
...        return func(*args, **kwargs)
...    return wrapper
... 
>>> def classAttrs(cls):
...     for key, val in vars(cls).items():
...         if callable(val):
...             setattr(cls,key, setMethodAttrs(val))
...     return cls
...  
... 
>>> 
>>> @classAttrs
... class trythis:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.firstvar=1
...       self.secondvar=2
...       self.thirdvar=3
...       self.fourthvar=4
...    def method1(self,firstvar=None,secondvar=None,thirdvar=None):
...       print("firstvar {}".format(self.firstvar))
...       print("secondvar {}".format(self.secondvar))
...       print("thirdvar {}".format(self.thirdvar))
...       print("fourthvar {}".format(self.fourthvar))
...    def method2(self, secondvar=None, fourthvar=None):
...       print("firstvar {}".format(self.firstvar))
...       print("secondvar {}".format(self.secondvar))
...       print("thirdvar {}".format(self.thirdvar))
...       print("fourthvar {}".format(self.fourthvar))
...   
...  
... 
>>> a=trythis()
>>> a.method1()
firstvar 1
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method1(firstvar=9)
firstvar 9
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method2(11)
firstvar 9
secondvar 11
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method1(19, thirdvar=21)
firstvar 19
secondvar 11
thirdvar 21
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method2(fourthvar=40)
firstvar 19
secondvar 11
thirdvar 21
fourthvar 40
>>>
```

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you have a better example than this hypothetical class?

Comment: I had classes with methods with arguments which I set with if a: self.a=a for each argument. This code repeated for every argument. I wanted to remove the repetitive code so this was my solution. Now you call a method and the arguments are set on the object by the call

Comment: also if you define the constructor with arguments they are automatically set as object attributes (def __init__(self,firstvar,secondvar,thirdvar,fourthvar) means you dont have to put in self.firstvar=, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...        if len(args)>1:
> ...           for x in range(1, len(args)):
> ...              setattr(args[0], formalArgs[x], args[x])
> ```

You’re pretty much re-inventing `zip` here, use that instead. To extract out the first (`self`) parameter, you can use `next` (in Python 3) or slicing (in Python 2). To get a consistent behaviour accross Python versions, you can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in Python 2.

Something along the lines of:

```
arguments = zip(formalArgs, args)
_, self = next(arguments)
for name, value in arguments:
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

You can also define your wrapper as `def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` to remove the need for `next` and already extract the value of `self` out of the `args` tuple. This will mean you’ll have to slice `formalArgs` though:

```
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    formal_args = inspect.getargspec(func)[0][1:]
    for name, value in zip(formal_args, args):
        setattr(self, name, value)
```

You also don't need to inspect `func` at each call as, since you're using a decorator, you’re pretty much guaranteed that this object will never change during the lifetime of the program. Besides, it may be more readable to use the name, rather than the index, of the attribute you’re trying to extract out of the nametuple (since Python 2.6).

Lastly, `getargspec` has been deprecated since Python 3.0, so you'd better off using `getfullargspec`. But this function doesn't exist in Python 2, so you can try a conditional import:

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import wraps
try:
    # Python 3
    from inspect import getfullargspec as getargspec
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from inspect import getargspec
    from itertools import izip as zip


def store_attributes(method):
   arguments_names = getargspec(method).args[1:]

   @wraps(method)
   def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
       for name, value in chain(zip(arguments_names, args), kwargs.items()):
           setattr(self, name, value)
       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

   return wrapper


def class_store_attributes(cls):
    for name, value in vars(cls).items():
        if callable(value):
            setattr(cls, name, store_attributes(value))
    return cls
```

Usage being the same, even though I still don't get why you would use `@class_store_attributes` on the whole class rather than `@store_attributes` on a per-method basis.

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of methods in the class I'm applying this to so I thought applying it to the class would be better

Comment: This sounds fishy. Don't you want to put the whole code for review? ;)

Comment: it might contain company secrets ;-)

Comment: >>> a=trythis(1,2,3,4)

Comment: when I instantiate with positional arguments I get:
a=trythis(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in wrapper
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'firstvar'
but it does work if I use the kwargs
a=trythis(firstvar=1,secondvar=2,thirdvar=3,fourthvar=4)

Comment: @amadain This should be fixed now

Comment: chain - I never saw that used. I remember it from the initial tutorial from python.org but this is the first time I've seen it used

Comment: @amadain Sorry, there was a missing import

Comment: its ok. I got it

Comment: after mentioning chain it had to be imported from itertools